# How do you dismiss the detail view in SwiftUI on an iPad/split view layout?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, swiftui

I'm attempting to dismiss the detail view in a master detail view on an iPad (e.g. if that item is deleted in the master view and needs to blank out the right hand side).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(tag: "item1", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 1", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 1")
                }

                NavigationLink(tag: "item2", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 2", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 2")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(tag: "item3", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 3", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
            }
            
            Text("Blank View")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let item: String
    @Binding var selection: String?
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail for \(item)")
            Button {
                selection = nil
//                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example that demonstrates the issue. When dismiss is pressed it nils the selection which on iPhone dismisses the detail controller. On the iPad it keeps the detail view there, rather than returning to the blank view.

Here is the view before selecting an item. You can see the blank view on the right hand side.
[image: Before selecting]

After selecting an item the left hand side is selected, and the right hand side shows the appropriate detail view.
[image: After selecting]

After dismissing the view by nilling the selection (or using the environment dismiss) the selection on the left disappears as it should, but the detail view on the right stays put. This should have disappeared and the blank view should show again.
[image: After dismissing]

Comment: any luck getting this answered? i've been working around it blows my mind why dismiss() simply does not work as usual. In the same view it works fine on iphone, but does not dismiss on iPad portrait nor landscape. iOS 15.

Comment: You can see my reply down below, You need to have an if statement that shows or hides the content view based on some state. For example if you have an object in a binding you can if else on either showing the content or an alternate blank view. A bit of a pain though for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out a solution that works however it requires some extra logic. It needs some sort of check to see if the data is there and if it isn't then conditionally show the main view or a blank view.

Here is the modified `DetailView` for the example I used in my question. If the selection binding is nil then display the blank view again.

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    let item: String
    @Binding var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        if selection != nil {
            VStack {
                Text("Detail for \(item)")
                Button {
                    selection = nil
                } label: {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("Blank View")
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of an `NSManagedObject` you can check `object.managedObjectContext != nil`. I decided to make this an extension to make this easier.

```swift
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    public func blankWithoutContext<BlankView>(_ object: NSManagedObject, blankView: () -> BlankView) -> some View where BlankView: View {
        if object.managedObjectContext != nil {
            self
        } else {
            blankView()
        }
    }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```swift
MyView()
    .blankWithoutContext(object) {
        Text("Blank View")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to give up the `splitView` (having the items on that sidebar), you can override the default navigation settings to make it behave as it would on an iPhone (using stacked navigation views), then the dismiss button works just fine. Add this modifier `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to `NavigationView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(tag: "item1", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 1", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 1")
                }

                NavigationLink(tag: "item2", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 2", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 2")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(tag: "item3", selection: $selection) {
                    DetailView(item: "Item 3", selection: $selection)
                } label: {
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
            }
            
            Text("Blank View")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly I'm not willing to give up the split, that's the main reason for the question. The stack navigation has its uses but I really want a split view here. 

I have a temp solution that works that I'll post if no one else has a more proper way. I appreciate the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this: I'm using `selection` parameter of a `List`, not of a `NavigationLink`. And when I need to pop, I set that `selection` back to `nil`. I think you might use `@Binding var selection` in your child view to set it from there. I have mine in a view model, since I need it to be there.